# GWT image update doesn't work in a callback

Tags: image, asynchronous, gwt, callback

I have Content Panel in which I add an image object without assigning an URL. Then I do a request to the server to return the URL of an image in the onSuccess method, but the image is not shown.

If I set the URL without calling server-side code it works, but when I use image.setUrl in the onSuccess method it doesn't work.

Do you know how to paint an image asynchronously?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using GXT? Which version? can you provide some code?

Comment: What do you see in `src` attribute of `img` element in DOM after `setUrl`?

Answer (score 0):

Make server call before rendering screen. After you receive response from server in success method make rendering of screen.

Comment: Thank you guys, I just implemented a workaround that consisted on adding several images and show/hide them depending on conditions. But the best is what you say, to call server before rendering.